# NumericUpDown ValueChanged event not working on entering values

Tags: winforms, numericupdown

Event not activates on entering values by using numbers on keyboard. It only activates when you use the up and down arrows. What I want is, It must activate on every keyboard stroke like textbox textchanged event.

I've tried few things but user had to press enter for activating the event. I don't want that.

It must be same like textbox event. Any ideas ? or another tool maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

NumericUpDown control fires the value changed event in the following scenarios

- When using Up/Down arrows of the control as you have mentioned.
- When the control loses focus after changing the value using keyboard input.
- When using Up/Down arrow keys in the keyboard.

Instead of ValueChanged you can use `KeyPress` event which fires for every keyboard key stroke.(*but keep in mind this event will only fire for keyboard numeric key press*)

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I weren't aware of keypress object. I combined keypress event with value changed so It solved my problem. I'll add the solution I combined as answer.

Comment: I Combined those events but It doesn't work in good order. Also I found keypress event is gives a struggle on numericUpDown. It changes the values by changing the focus on letters order on numericUpDown.

Comment: @OzanAyten What are you trying to do within ValueChanged event ? What logic do you have ? Why you want to use NumericUpDown control ? Can't you use Textbox ? you can also also prevent the user from typing non-numeric characters within textbox.

Comment: I'll use it for enter money values with two decimals. I use numericUpDown for solely visual reason. When you compare textbox and numericupdown. You'll know where to enter numeric value at first glare.

Comment: Ah for logic, I want to check it if valuechanged, "buttonSave" will be enabled. But if value turns back to same value. It should be disabled.

Comment: @OzanAyten Can't you make it ReadOnly(set the property to true) which will allow user to change the value only by clicking up/down of the control or keyboard up/down keys. in both cases ValueChanged event will fire.

Comment: I don't want to loose easy access to content. Like, copy/paste values. Using keyboard for easy change of values etc. Also, numbers differs so much (0,01 to 99999,99 etc).