# NumericUpDown ValueChanged event not firing while typing

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, numericupdown

I have a bound NumericUpDown control.

I want the `ValueChanged` Event to fire when either the up or down arrow is clicked or if the user changes the number.

When the up or down arrow is clicked the `ValueChanged` event does fire,
but not when I just type into the control.

```
// numericUpDownDiscountRate
// 
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.DecimalPlaces = 4;
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(133, 344);
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.Name = "numericUpDownDiscountRate";
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(115, 23);
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.TabIndex = 78;
this.numericUpDownDiscountRate.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.numericUpDownDiscountRate_ValueChanged);
```

I found a question that advises to use the [KeyPress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772951/numericupdown-valuechanged-event-not-working-on-entering-values)
However the keypress event happens before the value is updated.

How do I get the value of the control from within the key press?

```
private void numericUpDownDiscountPercent_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (loadingForm) return;
    try
    {
        loadingForm = true;
        var updn = sender as NumericUpDown;

        // updn.value does not include the key press and I don't know how to construct the value 
        MyCalculateRate(updn?.Value ?? 0);

        loadingForm = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Discount rate Key Press");
        loadingForm = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your custom NumericUpDown usercontrol ? Or from other UI framework?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown

Comment: Why do you have code that checks only numbers are typed into an NUD? It's redundant?

Comment: You may want to look into "TextChanged" event instead, because you want to be able to read the text before confirming (pressing enter etc) which the ValueChanged event waits for.  I believe the TextChanged event fires at the time that the text changes, rather than when the user confirms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Value` is changed only after validation, which occurs when the input is validated when the internal Edit Control loses focus or when the Value is retrieved, I suggest to introduce a *custom* value that works alongside the default `Value` property.

Note that when the Value Property is read, the input is not just validated but also the Text is re-set, so reading the `Value` Property while editing becomes quite difficult, since the caret is moved when the Text is reset.

When the Up/Down Buttons are pressed, also the Text is formatted, hence  `OnTextChanged()` is called and the custom value is set.

Implemented in a Custom Control here, but you can do ~the same using the event handlers of a standard NumericUpDown Control.
Don't read the `Value` property in `OnValueChanged()`, for the reasons previously explained.
Use `CurrentEditValue` while the Text is being edited. Or subscribe to the `CurrentEditValueChanged` event instead.
The Custom Control is DataBinding-friendly.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(true), DesignerCategory("code")]
public class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown {

    private static readonly object Event_CurrentEditValueChanged = new object();
    private decimal m_CurrentEditValue = 0M;

    public NumericUpDownEx() { }

    [Bindable(true), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public virtual decimal CurrentEditValue { 
        get => m_CurrentEditValue;
        internal set { 
            if (value != m_CurrentEditValue) {
                m_CurrentEditValue = value;
                OnCurrentEditValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        } 
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (decimal.TryParse(Text, out decimal value)) {
            CurrentEditValue = value;
            OnValueChanged(e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CurrentEditValueChanged {
        add {
            Events.AddHandler(Event_CurrentEditValueChanged, value);
        }
        remove {
            Events.RemoveHandler(Event_CurrentEditValueChanged, value);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCurrentEditValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Events[Event_CurrentEditValueChanged] is EventHandler evth) evth(this, e);
    }
}
```

Example of direct (One-Way) Binding to the `CurrentEditValue` Property:

```
[SomeTextBox].DataBindings.Add("Text", numericUpDpwnEx1, "CurrentEditValue", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Thank you. I put my validation project    at https://github.com/kgreed/UpDnTest

Comment: I made a few changes. I suppose that direct (one-way, since it's read-only for non-inheritors) binding to the new Property should be available. It uses standard .Net binding paradigm (`[Property] -> [PropertyChanged] event`) in WinForms. You can replace it with an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Or remove the event and the related method (`OnCurrentEditValueChanged`) if direct binding is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit "hocus pocus" but (in .netfw472 - haven't tried in netcore) if you bind an event handler to KeyUp that accesses the Value:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = numericUpDown1.Value; //I know it looks useless, but it seems to make ValueChanged fire more often
    }
```

it causes your ValueChanged to fire on every keypress and accessing `.Value` within ValueChanged will give you the current value..

"But why?!" you might ask... "I don't know; I've never looked.. but NumericUpDown isn't regarded as the most reliable control.."